# Crop focused object from image in C

Tags: c++, c, image, image-recognition

How to crop focused object from image? Can someone provide sources

For example:
1) I got picture
2) Then select some object at image with finger
3) Then I get result image with only selected object without foreground

I need something like
http://www1.idc.ac.il/toky/CompPhoto-09/Projects/Stud_projects/IrenaAviad/Web/

(but as Visual studio project)

How to achieve this ?

Can someone provide me info or code example ?

Comment: "only selected object **without foreground**"? What does that even mean?

Comment: I mean following. For example you have picture with 3 cats sitting near house. I touch random point of this photo. If this point coordinate will be close to one of the cats - I should get new photo but with only one cat presented. I need to get only one cat picture without other cats and background objects (grass,trees etc) I want to get C++ example of how to make such photo processing

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm from your link is discussed in the [GrabCut](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/visionimagevideoediting/segmentation/grabcut.htm) paper. You are unlikely to find a read-to-go Visual Studio project for this (though the technique is used in recent versions of [Microsoft Office](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office2010/archive/2009/11/30/more-about-background-removal-in-office-2010.aspx).)